# PHP Controller function instantiated before it's called

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I'm having a problem with a CRUD application form being displayed on a bootstrap modal.

The issue happens when the form's edit button send the  "editId" post var, the modal shows up but the values for the options of the select tag are displayed outside the form.

My controller looks like this:

```
public function editarUsuarioController(){
if (isset($_GET["editId"])) {       

    $dataController = $_GET["editId"];
    $data = Datos::editUserModel($dataController, "users");

    echo'<div id="editModal">
    <form method="post" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="roleEdit">Rol<span></span></label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                </span>
                <select name="roleTypes" class="form-control">
                    <option selected>
                        '.$data["rols"].'
                    </option>
                    '.$editOptions = MainController::viewRolesController().'
                </select>                                       
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" class="btn blue" value="Update">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn default">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>';
}   }
```

As you can see, I'm instantiating another controller from another file which lists the available roles which looks like:

```
public function viewRolesController(){

    $response= Datos::vistaRolesModel("roles");

    foreach($response as $row => $item){
        echo'<option value="'.$item["id"].'">'.$item["role"].'</option>';

    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by splitting up the echo and using a variable inside the original controller to store the values brought by the `vistaRolesModel()` model function so this is the new `editarUsuarioController()` controller function:

```
public function editarUsuarioController(){
if (isset($_GET["editId"])) {
    $dataController = $_GET["editId"];
    $data = Datos::editUserModel($dataController, "users");
    $roles   = Datos::vistaRolesModel("roles"); 
    echo'
    <div id="editModal">
        <form method="post" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="roleEdit">Rol<span></span></label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    </span>
                    <select name="roleTypes" class="form-control">
                        <option selected>
                            '.$data["rols"].'
                        </option>
                        ';
                        foreach($roles as $row => $item){
                            echo'<option value="'.$item["id"].'">'.$item["role"].'</option>';
                        }
                        echo'
                    </select>                                       
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <input type="submit" class="btn blue" value="Update">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn default">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    ';
}
```

}